# Bokeh : Different scales os stacked bar when hosted

Tags: bokeh

I have a plot which takes input from Goole sheets.

I get plot with two different scales while running main.py and when hosting on a web.

Can anyone let know the reason and solution ?

```
cmplot  = figure(plot_width = 600 , plot_height = 400, name = "com_meetings_plot")
cmplot.vbar_stack(stackers= ['pm','fp' ,'nd'] , x = 'yr', source = com_meetings_data 
       ,color=("#5ac18e","#F3F781","#F781BE"), width = 0.5, line_color = "black")

cmplot.toolbar_location = None
cmplot.xaxis.axis_label = "Year"
cmplot.yaxis.axis_label = "Number of Meetings"
```

date for graph

```
[{'Year': 2015, 'Planned_Meetings': 12, 'Actual_Meetings': 12, 'Further Plan': 0, 'Meetings Conducted': 12, 'Not Done': 0}, {'Year': 2016, 'Planned_Meetings': 12, 'Actual_Meetings': 8, 'Further Plan': 0, 'Meetings Conducted': 8, 'Not Done': 4}, {'Year': 2017, 'Planned_Meetings': 12, 'Actual_Meetings': 12, 'Further Plan': 0, 'Meetings Conducted': 12, 'Not Done': 0}, {'Year': 2018, 'Planned_Meetings': 12, 'Actual_Meetings': 12, 'Further Plan': 0, 'Meetings Conducted': 12, 'Not Done': 0}, {'Year': 2019, 'Planned_Meetings': 12, 'Actual_Meetings': 11, 'Further Plan': 0, 'Meetings Conducted': 11, 'Not Done': 1}, {'Year': 2020, 'Planned_Meetings': 12, 'Actual_Meetings': 3, 'Further Plan': 9, 'Meetings Conducted': 3, 'Not Done': 0}]
```

HTML code as below

```
  <div class="col-md-6";>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                    <div class = "x_title">  
                        <h3 class="card-title">Commitiee Meetings</h3>
                        <p class="card-text">Number of Meetings plan vs actual</p>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>    
                {{ embed(roots.com_meetings_plot) }}  
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

There are types of graphs I get

[When running main.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulvUc.png)

[When running on bokeh server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY7eF.png)

Comment: My guess is that you local setup and the remote one have different Bokeh versions, and one of them is really outdated. Try checking the versions. If you cannot do it on the remote setup, just add `import bokeh; print(bokeh.__version__)` at the top of the file.

Comment: Ah, disregard that - you did not provide the actual data that you're using. Your stackers have one set of columns, the provided data has a different one. The bad image looks like it uses year instead of the meetings number. So it seems like you just have bad code that converts whatever data you have into an instance of `ColumnDataStore`.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov Please check this com_meetings_data = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(
    fp = com_meetings_data.iloc[:,3],
    pm = com_meetings_data.iloc[:,4],
    nd = com_meetings_data.iloc[:,5],
    yr  = com_meetings_data.iloc[:,0])) the problem is that the graph is ok when I run main.py but not ok as app

Comment: Can you actually 100% guarantee that the columns in `com_meetings_data` stay at the same order? In any case, it's better to not rely on it and just use names. Apart from using the `Year` column where some other column should've been, I have no ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this based on the clue from @EugenePakhomv.

I used 
`df["Product"]` rather than `df.iloc` function.

Even though the issue is resolved , I am not sure what made the application to fail when I used iloc.